# Create a nested element with blank namespace in a schema definition

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I have a remote system that returns an XML similar to the one below.

```
<BalanceResponse xmlns="http://example.com/balance">
  <BalanceResult>
    <Balance xmlns="">
      <amount>10</amount>
    <Balance>
  </BalanceResult>
</BalanceResponse>
```

I created an xsd to match it

```
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/balance">
   <s:element name="BalanceResponse">
        <s:complexType> 
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="BalanceResult">
            <s:complexType> 
                      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Balance">
                         <s:complexType> 
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="amount" type="s:decimal" />
                          </s:complexType> 
                      </s:element>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:complexType>
</s:schema>
```

I use JAXB to generate the stub classes. However, I know that my (un/)marshaller cannot bind the Balance element because the namespace is different.

Question is, how can i declare a different (blank)namespace for my element Balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following.  Since `elementFormDefault` is `unqualified` all global elements (`BalanceResponse` and `BalanceResult` will be namespace qualified and all local elements (`Balance` and `amount`) won't be.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/balance" 
    xmlns:tns="http://example.com/balance" 
    elementFormDefault="unqualified">

    <element name="BalanceResponse">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element ref="tns:BalanceResult"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>

    <element name="BalanceResult">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="Balance">
                    <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                            <element name="amount" type="int"/>
                        </sequence>
                    </complexType>
                </element>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>

</schema>
```

If as in the XML Schema in your question put `elementFormDefault` as `qualified` then it would expect all of the XML elements to be namespace qualified.

Comment: Because `elementFormDefault` is set to `unqualified` only the top level XML elements will inherit the namespace defined as the `targetNamespace` for the XML schema.